# map applied to a function acting on list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I want to apply map() to  a list of strings, with the outcome being another list of strings.

The following code seems to have a minor issue that is preventing it from being executed. Any thoughts?

Suppose s is some list of strings. I define

```
def swap(s):
 for i in range(len(s)):
  if s[i].islower()==True:
    s[i]=s[i].upper()
  else:
    s[i]=s[i].lower()
 return s
```

now I want to execute the following

```
print(list(map(swap,s)))
```

but I get an error.

if input is s=['S','A','r','a'], I expect the output to be ['s','a','R','A']

Comment: What error exactly do you get? Post the whole error here for best results

Answer (score 2):

`map` sends each element of the `list` to the function passed to it. So basically, your `swap` is being called 4 times with each of the elements.

```py
def swap(ch):
    print(ch)
    if ch.isupper():
        return ch.lower()
    return ch.upper()

s = ['S', 'A', 'r', 'a']
print(list(map(swap, s)))
```

Would output:

```
S
A
r
a
['s', 'a', 'R', 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `swap` to `s`, the function is applied to each element of `s`. The first call is `swap(s[0])`, etc. The value of the parameter `s` in the function is a string, not a list. An attempt to modify a string via `s[i]=...` is illegal because strings are immutable.

You function must split the string into characters and then combine the transformed characters back into a string:

```
def swap(s):
    return "".join(c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower() 
                             for c in s)
```

Or, better yet, use the standard method `str.swapcase()`.

Comment: thanks DYZ. I was thinking about doing it using a more basic code, but this is fine

Comment: There is nothing non-basic here. All functions used are standard Python functions.